# Convert string "True" and "False" to 1 and 0

Tags: c#

I'm retrieving a string value of "True" or "False". I need to convert it to 1 or 0 respectively. What's the best way to do that? Currently I'm doing it this way....

```
var myValue = Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToBoolean(stringValue));
```

If I remove the ToBoolean part....

```
var myValue = Convert.ToInt16(stringValue);
```

.... then I get "Input string was not in a correct format" for the ToInt16 conversion. Am I doing this in the best way?

Comment: How should other strings be handled? Exception?

Comment: Literally typing your title into google gives you an answer.

Answer (score -2):

simple if/else approach

```
short result = stringValue == "True" ? (short)1 : (short)0;
```

Comment: lol feel free to comment my mistake